# Python code is not syntax highlighted in Pycharm notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

In the screenshot we see a pretty normal-ish python code cell within the `Pycharm` notebook viewer The viewer "understands" the notebook: it is bringing up the `managed Jupyter server` option and knows this is [python] code:

[image]

So then where did the syntax highlighting go to?  How can it be [re-]enabled ?

Comment: There's some suggestion towards the bottom of [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007678039-Wrong-Code-Highlighting-in-Jupyter-Notebooks).

Comment: @Wayne  Nice link: it contributes to an answer I added below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wayne was headed the right direction: that link he provided [Wrong Code Highlighting in Jupyter Notebooks](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007678039-Wrong-Code-Highlighting-in-Jupyter-Notebooks) had suggestion to reload the python interpreter.

Well in my case the interpreter is `Synapse Pyspark` and is grayed out since i'm presently running locally.  I need to figure out how to change the interpreter: will update here at that point.

**Update** I needed to edit the *json* source of the *ipynb* file to find and remove the *synapse* kernel.

[image]